# Grafana on Centos8: Unable to use "ad hoc filters"

Tags: grafana, influxdb, flux, centos8

I try to use `ad hoc filters` but `Data source` drop down list shows only "Grafana". In the bashboard I use InfluxDB as data source, plugin for that is installed by default. Dashboard queries work as expected.

Grafana version:

```
[root@ip-10-1-1-121 ~]# grafana-server -v
Version 7.4.3 (commit: 010f20c1c8, branch: HEAD)
[root@ip-10-1-1-121 ~]# grafana-cli -v
Grafana CLI version 7.4.3
```

OS:

```
[root@ip-10-1-1-121 ~]# cat /etc/os-release 
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.3 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.3"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8.3:GA"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.3
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.3"
```

Any suggestions?